# How to store a Tar file in Azure Devops Server 2020 Artifact

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-artifacts

As part of my CI process, I'm looking to store docker image files in Azure Artifact (Azure DevOps Server 2020)which is in tar format. Which I need to reference later for the next infra deployment.
I have created a feed-in Azure DevOps Server 2020 and I'm able to upload the .jar files to Azure Artifact but .tar files are being ignored.

As per Microsoft documentation, universal packages are not supported in the Azure DevOps server, does the tar file considered a universal package?

If yes, is there any workaround to store the tar file Artifact or Azure repo for my later reference to deploy the image in SIT infra?

Answer (score 1):

If your image is a result of the build process, you may upload it through standard build publish task: [PublishBuildArtifacts@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines)

Then you may download it in another build pipeline through: [DownloadPipelineArtifact@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-pipeline-artifact-v2?view=azure-pipelines)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I need to deploy the image in a different environment like SIT UAT, so im looking for an option.

Comment: @Julie you may use the same for release pipelines...just add pipeline (containing tag) as source artifact or download by with DownloadPipelineArtifact@2